# Custom UIPopoverBackgroundView: no drop shadow

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I've used this good [tutorial](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller/) to create a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView class.

It works well. The only problem is that I am not getting the typical UIPopoverController drop shadow and I want it. I've tried specifying it on the layer of my UIPopoverBackgroundView instance without success. My instance of UIPopoverController doesn't seem to have a public view to manipulate. Adding it to the popover content also doesn't work.

Probably really simple: **how do I add a drop shadow when using a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView class?**

*// UIPopoverBackgroundView.m*

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _borderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popover.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET)]];

        _arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popover-arrow.png"]];

        [self addSubview:_borderImageView];
        [self addSubview:_arrowView];

        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I needed to add the drop shadow to the `borderImageView`, not the view of the popover instance.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _borderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popover.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET)]];

        _arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popover-arrow.png"]];

        [self addSubview:_borderImageView];
        [self addSubview:_arrowView];

        _borderImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        _borderImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        _borderImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        _borderImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        _borderImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _borderImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        _borderImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 50;
        _borderImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10.0f, 10.0f);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Just thought I'd add that this worked for me, but I had performance issues. Rasterizing the background layer helped immensely:         'backgroundImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;'

Comment: Interesting - I didn't notice any significant lag (on iPad 2) but good to know.

Comment: Anyone reading this answer, **Do what @Maurizio said!**. Performance is not just improved, but all the performance issues caused by adding a shadow are diminished when `shouldRasterize` is set to `YES`!

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to add your own shadows. The base `UIPopoverBackgroundView` will do it for you. Just make sure to call super in your `layoutSubviews` implementation.

**EDIT:** My comment applies to apps targeting iOS 6.

Comment: +1 True. I came here after being surprised that my custom popover started dropping shadows after running it on iOS 6

Comment: Thanks for adding the update @ iOS6 - I had gone back to check under iOS5 after seeing your comment and calling super on `layoutSubviews` did not add the shadow.

Comment: I'm in iOS 6 and my UIPopoverBackgroundView is not showing the shadow :(

Comment: I'm in iOS 6 and my UIPopoverBackgroundView is showing the shadow ... though I don't want it to :)

Comment: Any idea how/where to *remove* the default shadow in a custom `UIPopoverBackgroundView` implementation?

Comment: @chaiguy To remove the default shadow, override `-(void)layoutSubviews` and leave it empty.